# Factors to why a civilization is not using past technology that is more advanced

Tags: technology, technological-development, history, scientific-development

In my world, there have been past ancient civilizations and empires who had better technology. Not just infrastructure, but also mechanical machinery, better inventions, and technics.

As the years go by, when newer, medieval civilizations pop up, they end up being less technologically developed, despite being more in the future. I am trying to add this to give some realism to my fictional history. What factors would cause a civilization to not use new or advanced technology, at least the advanced technology from the past?

Comment: Does present civilization have full means to utilize older technologies as well as enough details to implement them? In our history, technological development wasn't always linear - for example, barbarians who came after Romans didn't use quite a lot of Roman technology.

Comment: As written you're asking a very broad and open ended question. Site policy discourages overly broad questions, that focus on idea generation, or brainstorming, or questions that have many valid answers. Instead of asking us to list out every possible reason why an advanced technology could no longer be used, you figure out why for your world, and come to to ask for help resolving the specific issues you encounter.

Comment: Given the rate with which the questions you're asking are getting closed you may want to take advantage of [the sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7183/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where you can get feedback on how to improve your questions before posting them to the main site.

Comment: Whether you ask "What would justify..." or "How would I justify..." You're still asking an overly broad question with many valid answers. We're not here to generate ideas, brainstorm or build your world for you. Try to figure out the specific reasoning for your world on your own, and then ask for help resolving the specific issue you are struggling with. Or figure it out and then ask us whether the idea you came up with makes sense in context. Either way we'll be helping you with a specific problem.

Comment: This is just silly. You've made a minor change to the wording but not narrowed the question one jot, yet added in your note to the edit that you've "supplied more details" - which you most certainly have not. Please refer to the section of the help centre about  [ask] an on-topic question and ensure that you understand it.

Comment: It is one question. Where is this other question?

Comment: @Crafter Of the ten most recent questions you've asked (that haven't been deleted) 7 have been closed for various reasons. Please follow Jiminy Cricket's advice above and familiarize yourself with the rules of this site.

Comment: @Crafter You have to add world elements and intentions. What is **your** world right now, what do you want and not want to do along the main question? Otherwise it's like  you're asking "where's the nearest bakery?" to strangers you randomly phoned over the world. For me I have an excellent one in France, but it's certainly not yours, either in speciality, price range and distance. That's what you need to solve before posting new questions. See the difference with this [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/230473/80336), which just came out fresh of the sandbox oven!

Comment: The most recent edit is a re-phrasing and reassertion of what you've already stated, you've not told us in any detail whatever about the context. This is potentially asking for an endless list which would all be guesswork as we know next to nothing about your society. If you're going to edit again, then please put some thought into what sort of (specific) answer you're looking for, and how you will judge a best answer. No open-ended list, they simply don't work here.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's too advanced and they can't figure out how to use it. Or they know how to use some of it but not fully, which they know can lead to disastrous consequences.

Imagine electric vehicles. They know how to use them and even to some degree how they work, they might have the technology (mastered) for steam power or even gas. So they can drive electric vehicles if they find them without a problem, however once the battery is exhausted they might have nowhere to charge them (or know they have to charge them) and not have the materials needed to make a new battery that will work. They might have tried, with disastrous consequences (battery starting a fire etc.... leading to the vehicles being engulfed in flames, ball of fire style - enough to discourage attempting to recharge or replicate them - making them very rare and undesirable to use)

A lot more could be added to this line of development - and I encourage anyone else to take this (partial) answer and incorporate it to their own if wanted.

Answer (score -1):

**Feudal society**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serfdom

> Unlike slaves, serfs could not be bought, sold, or traded individually
> though they could, depending on the area, be sold together with
> land... Serfs who occupied a plot of land were required to work for
> the lord of the manor who owned that land. In return, they were
> entitled to protection, justice, and the right to cultivate certain
> fields within the manor to maintain their own subsistence. Serfs were
> often required not only to work on the lord's fields, but also in his
> mines and forests and to labour to maintain roads.

In your society, 98% of the populace are serfs working the land.  1.9% are servants and craftsmen and 0.1% are nobility.

The serfs are crushed with work.  They use the same methods in the farms and mines as their ancestors centuries ago.  They do not innovate.  Craftsmen might be interested in technology but their numbers are small as are their markets.  They might copy a sculpture from antiquity if they are able but that is as far as it goes.

Nobility are interested in maintaining the status quo, and innovation of any sort is a threat to that.  They actively quash innovation.

Answer (score -1):

**A Dark Age**

The original civilization was wiped out, one way or another. No one uses the better technology because they genuinely have no idea how to use it.

Civilization A was eliminated and civilization B is now in charge. Why did this happen? Any number of reasons. It could have been a natural cause such as a plague or an unnatural cause such as a war. Either way, the people who originally made the machines are dead and gone.

Perhaps the language that civilization A used to work with has been utterly forgotten, either because of linguistic drifting or purposeful quashing from the ruling class in an attempt to stamp out knowledge.

Imagine any post-apocalyptic setting. In such a world, knowledge about complicated ideas such as science and innovation tends to be left by the wayside in favor of survival. Old information, such as how to power the fancy technology that civilization A left behind is most likely going to be thrown by the wayside with time.

With time, the advanced technology will seem almost like magic to the people of civilization B. This could be another part of the reason why they do not use the technology. They fear it. View it as magic that was brought there by devils and witches.

Depending on the reason for civilization A's demise, the fear of using the technology could be real. If A was killed off by war and its war machines are still around, one of the first things children of B would be taught is to stay as far away from anything that looks like it could be the ruins of A.

This leads to the fear becoming deeply ingrained in their society. Even if things get better as time goes on, the deep-seated fear of the Ancient Ones could become such a normal part of the culture that no one wants to use it.

Perhaps the Ancient Ones are viewed almost as deities (or demons) and their technology is considered forbidden fruit. Touching one of the ancient artifacts would be like defiling sacred ground. Under those circumstances, no one would ever be allowed to touch it out of respect for the Ancients.