# Survivability of a suddenly increased aphelion

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, survival

I have long been wanting to write a story about Earth freezing relatively fast. In the past I have asked some questions here considering a scenario where Earth becomes a rogue planet... But I also want to keep it inhabitable for humans on the long term, and a rogue Earth would kill everyone in months or years.

So I have considered provoking a glaciation instead. Just as in a rogue Earth scenario, something would push Earth into a different orbit, but not enough to cause a solar escape.

I used an online physics calculator to figure that a 10% increase in the semi-major axis of Earth's orbit would increase the length of the year by approximately one month. If the push happens in July, it means the perihelion will be pushed to such a greater altitude that it becomes the new aphelion - and the Earth will be there during winter on the northern hemisphere. Having the northern winter last longer, combined with the increased distance from the sun, should cause global temperatures to drop considerably.

I am aiming for an impact similar to the eruption of the Tambora volcano in 1815, which led 1816 to be known as "the year without a summer", but harsher and permanent. But I don't know how to calculate how much the drop in global temperatures throughout the year would be in this case, nor if this would be such a catastrophe that a post-apocalyptic scenario with humans in it would be beyond optimistic.

Asides from the practically magical push that changes the Earth's orbit, I am aiming for full, scientific realism (though I am restraining myself from using the [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag here).

So... Is this longer winter possibly survivable, or would that surely be the last one humanity would see? If the latter, I'll consider scaling the orbital changes down.

Consider that the technological level of humanity when the orbit changes is exactly what we have today. In other questions here in the site we came to the conclusion that the change in orbit would be detected practically instantly, giving humanity some time to prepare for the worst. But we'd lose most if not all artificial satellites (which by itself would already cause a lot of disruption).

Comment: Can you use your calculator to calculate mean temperature, and then compare the temperature difference to a) the equator to cold populated climate difference, and b) the standard deviation of winter temperatures? If you're making the tropical mean winter temperature 5 SDs worse than the Siberian mean winter, mankind is in serious trouble. OTOH, if the tropics' winter temperature ends up like e.g. an average temperate country's winter, then the chances of survival are probably OK.

Comment: @jbh you're right. I changed the title, I hope it matches the question now.

Comment: @SeanOConnor the calculator is just for orbits, but I'll look into that

Comment: Close enough. Cheers!

Comment: @The Square-Cube Law We had a question a maybe three or four months ago about how to cause a world to get colder (I think). A couple of answers linked to calculators where you could plug in star type, planet size, mass, orbital radius, etc, and it spat out things like atmospheric pressure, mean temperature, etc.

Comment: @SeanOConnor If you ever track that question down, those calculators are fantastic and belong in the [list of Worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143606/40609).

Comment: I am struggling to answer.  Is the question "what sort of climate change would this orbit change produce?"

Comment: @Willk I have an idea of what kind of climate change this would cause. End of the thermohaline currents, snow during summer etc. Like the worst of the Little Ice Age, but harsher (though I don't know how much harsher). What I would like to know is whether this is too harsh for humans to continue existing on the long term, or if this causes human extinction within a handful lifetimes or less.

Comment: @Willk Do you remember a question where someone was looking for a sudden change to a planet (its light level, I think). You suggested that its orbit change ( Along the lines of "It just happened to happen, maybe because of a rogue planet") and I suggested using greenhouse gases to keep it warm despite being further away from the sun? Someone posted a fab planetary calculator. I've searched for an hour solid and can't find it.

Comment: Here is that ? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/230473/what-could-reduce-sunlight-on-an-earth-like-planet/230558#230558  But the only calculator is in your answer.  Maybe an account was deleted? In a fit of pique??

Comment: @SeanOConnor - is this it:  https://www.satsig.net/orbit-research/orbit-height-and-speed.htm

Comment: @Willk I think someone else had posted it in another question a week earlier. Thanks for tracking it down. I see its a 404 now :(

Comment: @JBH https://web.archive.org/web/20220519173816/https://www.astro.indiana.edu/ala/PlanetTemp/index.html

Comment: @SeanOConnor Rats! The wayback machine captures the page, but not the underlying code.

Comment: Look at the short story "A Pail of Air" by, I think, Asimov.  It doesn't answer your questions but shows people surviving in those conditions.

Comment: @JBH It worked for me. That's how I got the 15ish degrees that I mention below. Just tried it on a different device (Phones both times). The Build button that you need hides under the Wayback Machine banner at the top.

Comment: @SeanOConnor Ah-hah! So it does! That's a cool tool, I'm glad it was added to the resource page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The tropics will do fine.**

Glaciers.  Mammoths!  The cold, the cold.  And we already painted the whole cave.   But south of all that it is still pretty nice.  It might get nicer.  It did during the little Ice Age.

[Tracing the effects of the Little Ice Age in the tropical lowlands of eastern Mesoamerica](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2000453/)

> Our data provide evidence that the densest tropical forest cover and
> the deepest lake of the last two millennia were coeval with the
> LIA.... The high tropical pollen accumulation rates limit LIA's winter
> cooling to a maximum of 2 degrees C. Tropical vegetation expansion
> during the LIA is best explained by a reduction in the extent of the
> dry season as a consequence of increased meridional flow leading to
> higher winter precipitation.

Thicker forest, deeper lakes.  Sounds not too bad for human survivors!
When average global temperatures cool, it is because high latitudes get really cold.  The same is true for global warming - it is the high latitudes driving the change.  The tropics do not change that much in either scenario.  I think in your superbad little Ice Age scenario, the tropics will stay nice for humans.  Maybe they will get nicer!  Because a lot of the tropics are pretty freaking hot right now.

Comment: Second this. According to the calculator we found, 10% orbital radius distance = 15 deg C mean temperature. Challenging, but life will go on in the tropics, unless nukes get launched.

Answer (score 0):

Willk is right. All evidence points to the southern hemisphere being warmer due to many reasons: lower albedo due to less land mass, the fact that it is summer there during aphelion (which I am changing, but alas), currents etc.

Thanks to the comments in the question I was reminded of our [list of worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143606/40609). I played around and found this simulator that I liked: [Monash Simple Climate Model](https://sci-web46-v01.ocio.monash.edu/mscm/greb/cgi-bin/scny_i18n.py?scenario=37&variable=01&locale=EN) (now offline). I am linking directly to a simulation that includes changes in orbital distance.

The simulator is assuming a mostly circular orbit, whereas the one I suggested is thrice as eccentric as our current one. So I think what would happen is somewhere between the results in the simulator and current reality, leaning a bit towards the simulation since the winter will be much longer than the summer. To be fair, I adjusted the simulation to an smaaller global increase instead to 1.06 AU, thinking it will match my model more closely. This is what we have for surface temperatures:

[image: A simulation of global temperatures with an increased distance from the Sun]

And this is ice coverage year-round:

[image: Ice cover on the planet with an increased distance from the Sun]

North and Central America, as well as most of Eurasia would be covered in ice year-round. US and China in particular would be under glaciers. It would be the end of agriculture (at least as we know it) in those places, causing huge famines and mass migration from the populations to more equatorial regions.

But South America and Africa would have huge spans where it would be a livable ~14 C (57F) year round. It is possible to grow crops in those regions, and our ancestors of dozens of millennia ago have fared well against worse odds (not considering the potential for nuclear annihilation).

Oddly enough, Australia would be on the path to enact a polar version of Mad Max.