# What greenhouse gas could increase the temperature of a planet with the least damage to living beings?

Tags: science-based, biology, atmosphere

Following [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/230473/what-could-reduce-sunlight-on-an-earth-like-planet). After a certain incident, my Earth-like planet now only receives 0.3% of the sunlight it was originally receiving.

To compensate for this, someone, as an answer to my last question suggested using greenhouse gasses to raise the temperature back to normal. I think it's the simplest way to resolve the problem, however I don't know much about how the atmosphere works and which gas might be the most suitable.

The chosen gas (or gasses) will be present in large quantities, so it should:

- Not be toxic to most living beings (ie allow for life as we know it to continue on)
- If it has a noticeable effect (breathing etc), most living beings have to be able to adapt to it (or even evolve over long periods of time)
- Be able to stay in the atmosphere for a very long time, OR be easy to maintain (maybe through facilities releasing the gas periodically)
- Not involve constant clouds/covering of the sky
- Not have unwanted effects such as the high flammability that happens when you increase O2.

The civilization is technologically advanced so maybe unwanted side effects could be mitigated, and there is "magic" though I'd rather not use that if possible.

I don't mind using more than one gas to do the job, and/or decreasing the concentration of existing gasses in the atmosphere, etc.

Comment: Are you committed to a single gas? A mixture would work much better, since a single gas con only absorb certain wavelengths.

Comment: @Matthias Not necessarily. As long as it works. I'll edit the question to make it more clear, thanks

Comment: There is a different problem: you don't have enough incoming sunlight to keep most plants alive. This means you have no primary food production, and everything dies of that. Growing plants under artificial light is *possible* but takes a lot of energy.

Comment: @JohnDallman I'll be tackling each problem, one at a time. Thinking about everything at once is overwhelming, that's why for each question I assume everything else is normal. Plant life is something I'll figure out later c:

Comment: "most living beings have to be able to adapt to it" made me think. Do you want to have animals on your planet that live outside and eat plants that grow outside?
Because with 0.3% of sunlight I doubt that any plants will survive, no matter the temperature

Comment: @elPolloLoco What do you mean, "outside"? Most life right now is not "inside"? Also, as I said in a previous comment I'll figure out the plant problem later, I'm going through this one step at a time

Comment: @Lulullia I mean outside of buildings, in the wild. Okay, if you don't care about the part that plants need sufficient sunlight to survive, then it is not important.

Comment: The most potent GHG on Earth, water, does not fit your bill?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape Wouldn't that make it permanently cloudy?

Comment: Indeed, I haven't seen your requirement for 'no clouds' - that's difficult to get around then with water vapour only. There are the possibilities of cloudless steam atmospheres - but to reach the temperatures require you would need more instellation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer: A combination of multiple gases works best. Fluorinated gases are probably most powerful. It is probably not enough to compensate for the decrease of incoming radiation.**

Lets take a look at the greenhouse effect in general:
[image]
*source: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/meteo3/l2_p7.html*

Every gas absorbs a certain wavelength, so a higher concentration off this gas absorbs more light of this wavelength. The part that is higher than ~0.8 microns is expecially important. This is the infrared spectrum and the spectrum of the thermal radiation that is emitted by planet earth. If this radiation, that would just go into space, is blocked, the planet is heating up.

CO2 is the most popular here, but is mostly a problem here on earth because there is so much of it. It is not very toxic if concentrations don't go into the percent range, but causes acidification in the oceans, so it cuases problems there

CH4 is not really toxic. It is flammable, but only in high concentrations, so you could still add a lot of it to the current atmosphere and cause a huge greenhouse effect without getting to explosive/flammable concentrations. It is not very stable (half-life of ~100 y), but can be replenished easily if there are natural gas deposits on the planet

N2O is mostly non-toxic (was used for a sedative, but is not so non-toxic that it can be used for this without concern). It requires some energy to produce and is not that stable, so the effort would be bigger, but it works well otherwise

Fluorinated gases (not in the graphic) are probably the most powerful here. They cause only ~2% of todays effect, but only because of their low concentration. You could certainly create the strongest effect per mass with this one. It is kind of toxic but more like potential cancer in a few decades than immediate death (depends of course on the concentration). I am not sure about the stability of fluorinated gases, but fluorinated compounds in general are extremely stable.

So in summary, fluorinated gases are probably the fastest most efficient way to create a strong greenhouse effect. Mostly because the necessary amount is much lower than for the other ones. It would still be a good idea to also exploit the other ones. Expecially CH4 since you only have to drill into a few deposits and let the gas get into the air (be careful about explosions in the vicinity). However, I doubt that you can compensate for a decrease of incoming radiation to 0.3 % of the original value with a greenhouse effect. Keep in mind that the current increase of the greenhouse effect on earth might decrease outgoing radiation by only ~2-3% until the end of the century in the worst-case scenario.

**This is an answer to the comment of @Lulullia:**

I will go a little deeper in the specifics of the greenhouse efffect and thermal radiation in general: Every object emitts thermal radiation, the amount of the radiation is determined by the objects temperature. For hot objects (i.e. the sun) we can see this radiation (sunlight), for colder objects (earth surface) this is not possible (this is also why things start glowing when heated up). If a cold planet in space without an atmosphere is hit by sunlight, it reflects a part of it (albedo) and absorbs the rest. The absorbed radiation heats the planet up and increases its heat loss through thermal radiation until the energy loss through radiation equals the energy of the absorbed sunlight. Greenhouse gases absorb some of the outgoing radiation, so some of the outgoing radiation is "trapped" and the planet heats up further until the energy of outgoing radiation equals the absorbed radiation again.

Planet earth receives around ~340 W/m^2 (averaged for every latitude and the night side). This would lead to an average temperature of ~-18°C without greenhouse effect. The actual average temperature is ~15°C, so the greenhouse effect increases the temperature by ~33°C. Anthropogenic climate change will increase this by a few degrees until the end of the century (even in the worst-case scenario not more than 6°C).

Your planet would receive about 0.3% of ~340W, so about 1W. This would lead to a equilibrium temperature of ~-210°C.

Basically all outgoing thermal radiation by the earth is in the wavelengths above 0.8 microns (see graphic). As you can see, a lot of this radiation is already blocked. Blocked radiation does not mean, that it is not leaving the system at all, since the atmosphere itself heats up and emits thermal radiation as well.

If it would be possible to block all this radiation, the increase in temperature could maybe be doubled (wild guess) but you'd still be way below -100°C, even when tripled.

I used some simplifications and non-linearities here, but I think the general picture is still reasonable.

Comment: The last sentence is the key and should be put at the top of the answer. Not even an actual glass covered greenhouse would raise the inside temperature sufficiently.

Comment: @AlexP Thank you. I added it to the short answer.

Comment: I don't think the CO2 is projected to decrease outgoing radiation by 2% to 3% by the end of the century. It is projected to increase the existing greenhouse effect by something less than that. The existing effect is dominated by water, by a wide margin.

Comment: @BobaFit I was referring to the RCP8.5 scenario. I did not specify, which gases cause the decrease (because I don't know). H2O will certainly play a major role. I did not write about H2O since the amount of it in the atmosphere cannot be increased by just emitting it, but is rather controlled by atmospheric dynamics (rain, evapotranspiration).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the breakdown. Could you please explain why it is that raising the temperature sufficiently wouldn't be possible with greenhouse gasses?

Comment: Oooh I see. So it depends on the heat radiated by the planet. What if, then, the increase in greenhouse gas happens while the planet still receive 100% sunlight? (the humans would produce it in preparation for the decrease in sunlight). Or, if they generate enough heat through other means that could then be radiated out? Basically as I understand it, in order to heat up the planet, the heat needs to be "trapped" by the atmosphere, so any heat source that comes from the inside would do the trick, right?

Comment: @Lulullia The heat cannot be "trapped" completely and therefore not permanently. The new (very cold) equilibrium temperature will still be reached, if the planet is heated up in advance, it will just take longer. With the current technology, there is nothing here on earth humans could use to generate enough heat to stop the cooling over a longer time. If they would burn enough fossil fuels to create as much energy as reaches the earth from the sun, they would use up all known oil deposits in less than a day. I don't see any way to compensate for such a drastic decrease of solar radiation.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for the input, it gives much food for thought! I guess I'll have to find a "magical" way then - in the meantime I'm accepting this answer. Thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult to produce sufficient greenhouse gas to effect temperature, but the best option is Sulphur hexafluoride which is 22,800 times more potent a greenhouse gas than carbon dioxide. It is also very stable and will remain in the atmosphere for thousands of years.

https://www.epa.gov/eps-partnership/sulfur-hexafluoride-sf6-basics

Answer (score 1):

## Sulfur Hexafluoride

As @Slarty pointed out in the answers, sulfur hexafluoride seems to be what you are looking for.

SF6 is extremely stable, inert and also non-toxic, unlike most other fluorinated gases. It is about 23,000x more potent than CO2, as a greenhouse gas. The best part is that it is comparatively easy to produce. It is produced industrially by oxidizing (fluoridizing?) sulphur with fluorine gas.

SF6 has virtually no effect on breathing, though you may need to exhale more frequently, to remove this dense gas. Remember SF6 is like 6x denser than air, so your species may need to exhale once in a while to remove it, other than that, it has virtually no effect on the body, i.e. no cancer or inflammation.